# Convert french to english when upload as a csv file in php

Tags: php

I am using this method for convert French to English. Its working well when I get french characters from my html form. But I've to upload csv file which contains some french characters. It didn't convert while upload csv files.

This is my code while uploading csv

```
function UploadQuiz(){
   $row =& $this->getTable('quiz');
   $fileName='uploadFile';
   $fileName=$_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
   $f = fopen($fileName,"r");

   $success_counter=0; $failure_counter=0;
   while ( ($data = fgetcsv($f, 10000, ",") ) !== FALSE ){
     //perform string escapes so data is entered into database correctly
     $quiz_question = $data[0];
     $option_a = $data[1];
     $option_b = $data[2];
     $option_c = $data[3];
     $option_d = $data[4];
     $option_e = $data[5];
     $quiz_answer = $data[6];
     $quiz_explanation = $data[7];
     $quiz_difficulty = $data[8];
     $chapter_id = $data[9];

     $chapter=$this->check_chapter_id_exist($this->_data['course_id'],$chapter_id);
     if(!$chapter->chapter_id){
       $failure_counter++;
       continue;
     }

     $data['quiz_id'] = '';
     $data['course_id'] = $this->_data['course_id'];
     $data['quiz_question'] = $this->_convertgsm->convertgsm($quiz_question);
     $data['quiz_optionA'] = $this->_convertgsm->convertgsm($option_a);
     $data['quiz_optionB'] = $this->_convertgsm->convertgsm($option_b);
     $data['quiz_optionC'] = $this->_convertgsm->convertgsm($option_c);
     $data['quiz_optionD'] = $this->_convertgsm->convertgsm($option_d);
     $data['quiz_optionE'] = $this->_convertgsm->convertgsm($option_e);

  return $data;
}
```

Here my method in my php file:

```
function convertgsm($data){
    $normalizeChars = array(
    '`'=>"'",'Ë'=>'E','Â'=>'A','À'=>'A','Í'=>'I', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Î'=>'I',    'Ä'=>'A','Ç'=>'C','Ò'=>'O','Ï'=>'I','È'=>'E','Ó'=>'O','É'=>'E','Ô'=>'O','Ê'=>'E','Õ'=>'O','Ö'=>'O','ê'=>'e','Ù'=>'U','ë'=>'e','Ú'=>'U','ë'=>'e','Ú'=>'U','î'=>'i','Û'=>'U','Û'=>'U','Ü'=>'U','ô'=>'o','Ý'=>'Y','õ'=>'o','â'=>'a','û'=>'u','ã'=>'a','ÿ'=>'y','ç'=>'c','ï'=>'i'    
    );

    $result_data =  strtr($data, $normalizeChars);
    return $result_data;
  }
```

Could you help me to convert french to english while uploading csv files?

Comment: "while uploading" means you want it to be read and replaced while being transferred?

Comment: I just parse the uploaded data from my csv file.Then pass as a argument to that function.

Comment: Can you add your code you are using to upload your CSV .... .. i think i can help

Comment: Added code.Please check.

Comment: Oh .. just seen your update ... i would update my code to fit your usage now

Comment: Quick question .. why are you returning `$data` that would only work if your CSV has only one line `$data` should be `multiarray` not single `array`

Comment: yes i know.Dont care about return arrays.I want replace french to english only..

Answer (score 1):

Usage  1

```
$translate = new TranslateCSV ();
$str = 'who will win à wôrld cup ?';
var_dump ( $translate->customStrtr ( $str ) );
```

Output

```
 string 'who will win a world cup ?' (length=26)
```

Usage 2

```
$translate = new TranslateCSV ();
$translate->process ( "PATH_TO_UPLOADED CSV" );

if (! empty ( $translate->getErrors () )) {
    print_r ( $translate->getErrors () );
} else {
    echo "CSV Transalation Completed";
}
```

Class

```
class TranslateCSV {
    private $chars = array (
            '`' => "'",
            'Ë' => 'E',
            'Â' => 'A',
            'À' => 'A',
            'Í' => 'I',
            'Ì' => 'I',
            'Ã' => 'A',
            'Î' => 'I',
            'Ä' => 'A',
            'Ç' => 'C',
            'Ò' => 'O',
            'Ï' => 'I',
            'È' => 'E',
            'Ó' => 'O',
            'É' => 'E',
            'Ô' => 'O',
            'Ê' => 'E',
            'Õ' => 'O',
            'Ö' => 'O',
            'ê' => 'e',
            'Ù' => 'U',
            'ë' => 'e',
            'Ú' => 'U',
            'ë' => 'e',
            'Ú' => 'U',
            'î' => 'i',
            'Û' => 'U',
            'Û' => 'U',
            'Ü' => 'U',
            'ô' => 'o',
            'Ý' => 'Y',
            'õ' => 'o',
            'â' => 'a',
            'û' => 'u',
            'ã' => 'a',
            'à' => 'a',
            'ÿ' => 'y',
            'ç' => 'c',
            'ï' => 'i' 
    );

    private $output = array ();
    private $errors = array ();
    private $charsKeys = array ();
    private $charsValues = array ();
    function setChars($chars) {
        $this->chars = $chars;
    }

    function getErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    function customStrtr($str) {

        if (empty ( $this->charsKeys )) {
            $this->charsKeys = array_keys ( $this->chars );
        }

        if (empty ( $this->charsValues )) {
            $this->charsValues = array_values ( $this->chars );
        }

        $str = str_replace ( $this->charsKeys, $this->charsValues, $str );
        $str = iconv ( 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str );
        return $str;
    }

    function process($csvFile, $csvOut = "") {
        if (! is_file ( $csvFile )) {
            $this->errors [] = "CSV  files does not exist";
            return false;
        }

        if (! empty ( $csvOut ) && ! @touch ( $csvOut )) {
            $this->errors [] = "Can't Create Output CSV";
            return false;
        }

        $fpRead = @fopen ( $csvFile, "r" );

        if (! empty ( $csvOut )) {
            $fpWrite = fopen ( $csvOut, 'w' );
        }

        while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $fpRead, 1000, "," )) !== FALSE ) {
            $num = count ( $data );
            $field = array ();
            for($c = 0; $c < $num; $c ++) {
                $field [] = $this->customStrtr ( $data [$c] );
            }

            if (! empty ( $csvOut )) {
                fputcsv ( $fpWrite, $field );
            }
        }
        fclose ( $fpRead );

        if (! empty ( $csvOut )) {
            fclose ( $fpWrite );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I entered the data "who will win à wôrld cup ?" in my csv file.I just print string.It show me "who will win � w�rld cup ? ".So i can't convert.Any idea ?

Comment: I just print after  $quiz_question = iconv ( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $quiz_question ); and print utf8 only..Output:
who will win..Any other method ?

Comment: Hold On  .. I found a solution

Comment: Hi..I got 1 doubt.If i had text like élephant.These character(é) i didnt mentioned in my private array, $chars.It should be diaply as élephant.But it show me �lephant.Can u help me ??

Comment: I just now saw that link.That is 100 % correct.But i need a output like ""who will win a world cup ? élephant".The é should performed as é only.This is my problem.So only i didnt mentioned in that array.

Comment: I've tried so many ways.Included the data with élephant in my csv file.Still i cant display a result élephant.It show me �lephant.Could you help me ???